# Does this sentence make sense? If not, how can it be improved?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence

The consensus on whether studying individually is more effective than studying within a group has not been reached yet.

Although it seems okay for me, I think the sentence above can be improved but I don't know how.

Comment: I don't usually see "consensus" with a definite article in this type of sentence.  I'd also rather put the word consensus with the modifying phrase "has not been reached yet" to rearrange the whole sentence as, "Consensus has not been reached yet on whether studying individually is more effective than studying within a group."

Answer (score -1):

The passive voice here is clunky, although changing "...has been" to "researchers have..." is a bit of a cop-out.

I might try:

> There is no consensus yet on whether studying individually is more
>   effective than studying within a group.

Or:

> Researchers have not yet reached [a] consensus on whether studying
>   individually is more effective than studying within a group.